# jquery span button saying "Button1_Click is not defined"

Tags: c#, jquery

```
using Visual.Web.Developer.2010.Express;
using SQL.Server.Management.Studios.R2.Express;
```

What I'm trying to do, is get a button to run some C# when a button is clicked.. Sounds simple, right?.. I'm stuck at this part.
I have a span (Jquery UI button) being created when the user keypress's in an HTML input. As soon as they click the span, it saves what the user inputed and sends it to the database... Well, not quite yet. I'm building this and I'm stuck at this part.

One would attach the button click via attribute in the span tag, correct?

```
<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon-disk ui-icon saveButton" title="Save" style="float:left" onclick="Button1_Click"></span>
```

*C#*

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

Looks pretty simple, right? When I run this in debug, Firebug reads "Button1_Click is not defined"
.
.
.
Give me some insight here please!
*My HTML/Javascript code*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.hexen').after('<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon-disk ui-icon saveButton" title="Save" style="float:left" onclick="Button1_Click"></span>')// ui icon

    .keypress(function () {
        $(this).next('.saveButton').show();
    }); //adds ui icon

        $('.ui-state-default').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    }); //ui icon hover

        $('.saveButton').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).prev().attr('id'); //used in the "data" attribute of the ajax call
            var value = $(this).prev().val(); //used in the "data" attribute of the ajax call

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx",
                data: "{Id: " + id + ", Value: " + value + "}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            $(this).hide();
        }); //runs ajax call and removes ui-icon after .saveButton is clicked

    }); //end .ready
</script> 

<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate1"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate2"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate3"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate4"/><br />
<input type="text" class="hexen" id="investigate5"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `onclick="Button1_Click"` is trying to fire a function in javascript called `Button1_Click`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Button1_Click` is a server side button click handler which you cannot call it from client side using `onclick` attribute.

`onclick` will always look for handler or method on the client side JavaScript code.

You have to use `Asp.Net` button control which will render the necessary method on the page to perform postback to the server.

Once you click on `Asp.Net` button it will submit the current page to the server with necessary details to asp.net framework so that it will execute the required button click handler.

E.g. You can use `LinkButton` control like this and specify `OnClick` property to `Button1_Click` and `OnClientClick` property to call any client side javascript method.

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="Click me!" 
      OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" 
      OnClientClick="clientSideJavaScriptFunction()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it you don't need the 'onclick' handler for the span since you're binding to it in the javascript anyway:

```
$('.saveButton').click(....);
```

Also the `onclick` handler that you've got on the space is referencing a server side handler for C# events, not a client side handler for javascript events.  The value of `onclick` must be a function available to the client side code in javascript.  If you want to post data to the server on a button click then you need to do an AJAX request (like you are) in the javascript.

Finally the event handler you've trying to bind to `.saveButton` in the javascript won't work as you're trying to bind it (probably) before the document has finished loading.  Move the event binding into the document.ready block after you've called `after` on `.hexen`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how it works in C#, but I think you need to reference the function in the URL of the ajax call.

`url: "Default.aspx/Button1_Click",`

`Button1_Click` may have to be a public function for this to work.

**EDIT:** Check out the "Calling the page method with jQuery instead" section of this page: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/